# How to automatically determine best .NET type match of a value

Tags: c#, types

I'm working on a T4 template to automatically generate a C# class definition from an XML file. For each element in the XML document I'd like to determine the type of the content in that element. Is there a framework class that handles automatically determining a type from a string value?

Comment: No, since there's no single best way to do so, in any case: `int` or `long`? `decimal` or `double`? or why not just `string`? (just because it says "1" for this particular doesn't mean it's not supposed to be a string in general!). All in all, this sounds like a bad idea to begin with. What is your use scenario for it?

Comment: Check out RestSharp (restsharp.org) and it might make more sense as a use case. The WCF REST Toolkit has a 'Paste XML as Types' function that does this, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very interesting question but I am afraid you are going to have a tough time finding anything in the FCL that will do this.

If you think about it, your problem is a rather unique one, you have a known type as a conversion source and an unknown output type.  This doesn't come up too often in day-to-day coding using a framework like .NET.

Since the .NET framework is designed to be used with strongly-typed languages, types are very important and most of the time we know what type we want and can request a conversion from some generic source (like a string or an object) to that specific type.  That is why we have casting, conversion methods (like `Convert.ToInt32` and such), and similar things.  They are all designed to allow us to directly state the output type of the conversion since we know what it is that we want to get.

All that being said, I would be interested to see if someone else has written something like this because the parsing that would be involved in getting this to work must be very similar to the C# compiler itself in the way that literal values are handled in source code.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm going to end up having a list of supported types and just checking them one by one using a bunch of TryParse calls until one works and using that.

Comment: @John - Unfortunately that may be your best option.

Comment: It won't be the end of the world. There's only so many CLR types you can represent in XML. I learned that when writing my own deserializer :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the reflected source of [**XSD.exe**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) and/or the some of the code in the [**System.Xml.Serialization.Advanced.SchemaImporterExtension**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.advanced.schemaimporterextension.aspx) class where you can control some of the advanced serialization stuff.  In the past XSD has done a pretty good job of getting a starter schema file generated from a XML file.